# How to make texts and canvases responsive with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, text, canvas, font-size

I want to design something like twitter [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap) homepage texts on github.

As you can see, when you resize the browser window, texts sizes will be decrease and increase automatically.

I have tried fittextjs.com but that didn't work at all

**how can i do this?**

And the second question is: how to make a responsive section with twitter bootstrap?

I have coded a template and I've used a jquery countdown in it, but this jquery countdown's js files sets the width and height for canvas element automatically.

How can I make `section > div > canvas` responsive with bootstrap ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the media flag in your CSS file like that :

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    *
    {
        font-size: smaller;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    *
    {
        font-size: larger;
    }
}
```

When the screen's with is thiner than 700 px, all fonts are smaller than default size. When the screen's width is larger than 1200px, all fonts are larger than default size.

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreT/FbNJs/